# Django-REST: Proper way to add API to get entity via another field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, api-design

I'm super new to Python/Django/Django-REST, but I've managed to follow the [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and create my own API similar to the tutorial.

In my app, I have a model called `Toggle`, with a unique field called `feature_key`.

Following the tutorial, the default way to get a `Toggle` is by using the ID, i.e.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/toggles/1/
```

And it shows up in the browsable API page as a clickable link.

---

My question is, how do I add another endpoint to directly get a toggle via its `feature_key`? Maybe something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/toggles/key/category.key_1/
```

(I'm not sure if this is a "correct" way to design API)

How do I make this endpoint to be visible in the browsable API so that other devs are aware that this endpoint exists?

---

`toggle/views.py`:

This is almost the same as the tutorial's view.py

```py
# imports here


@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'toggles': reverse('toggle-list', request=request, format=format)
    })


class ToggleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Toggle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ToggleSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

`toggle/serializers.py`:

Also similar to the tutorial

```py
class ToggleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.username')
    is_enabled = serializers.BooleanField(initial=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Toggle
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'feature_key', 'description', 'is_enabled', 'created_at', 'created_by']


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    toggles = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='toggle-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'username', 'toggles']
```

`toggle/urls.py`:

Same as tutorial

```py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'toggles', views.ToggleViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Is the `feature_key` unique? If so then a Slugfield otherwise you might want to loof at [filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Comment: yup it's unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the tutorial...

You can make following changes:
**urls.py**

replace this

```
path('toggles/<int:pk>/', views.toggles_function),
```

with this:

```
path('toggles/<feature_key>/', views.toggles_function),
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def snippet_detail(request, key):
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(feature_key=key)
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

you can get the link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/toggles/<feature_key of entry>/`

if you want link like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/toggles/key/category.key_1/
```

in **urls.py**

```
path('toggles/<pk>/<feature_key>/', views.toggles_function),
```

and in **views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
    def snippet_detail(request, pk, key):
        try:
            snippet = Snippet.objects.get(feature_key=key) # snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

**suggestion**

You don't need use two fields from same model in url (like pk and feature_key both) if both are unique fields. You can get the instance from any of them.

Comment: How do I change `urls.py` if I'm using a url router (from [the tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#using-routers))?

Also do you think it's a good idea (API design wise) to have both endpoints? (getting by id and by `feature_key`)?

Comment: They're similar to the views and serializers found in the tutorial, but I've amended the question to add them

Comment: @Edwin try "router.register(toggles/<feature_id>', views.UserViewSet)". not sure if this works.